# Bootstrap td centered with text left aligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following table. What I want is to position the content of each td in its middle (centered) and keep the text left aligned. Data will be dynamic and I want to keep the table responsive.

```
<table class="table table-hover">

    <tr>
       <td><a href="">Inter Milan</a></td>
       <td><span class="label label-default">0 - 1</span></td>
       <td><a href="">Lazzio Roma</a></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
       <td><a href="">Bayern Munich</a></td>
       <td><span class="label label-default">3 - 3</span></td>
       <td><a href="">Herta Berlin</a></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I tried to solve it using the CSS

```
table td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

but I still want the text to be left aligned (for example, Inter and Bayern on the same alignment level).

Note that I am using **table-layout: fixed** on different tables on same page to keep same layout on different tables.

Comment: col-md but couldn't solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost the best solution I could find. I left aligned the first column, centered the second, and right aligned the last. I added a starting and ending tds in order to have content in the center. I don't know if you can beautify it to a better one. If not, it's a good solution to use :)

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><a href="">Inter Milan</a></td>
    <td style="text-align:center">
       <span class="label label-default">0 - 1</span>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: right;"><a href="">Lazzio Roma</a></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><a href="">Bayern Munich</a></td>
    <td style="text-align: center">
       <span class="label label-default">3 - 3</span></td>
    <td style="text-align: right;"><a href="">Herta Berlin</a></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could play around with the padding:

```css
td:nth-child(1) a{
  padding-left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-hover">
      <tr>
         <td><a href="">Inter Milan</a></td>
         <td><span class="label label-default">0 - 1</span></td>
         <td><a href="">Lazzio Roma</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><a href="">Bayern Munich</a></td>
         <td><span class="label label-default">3 - 3</span></td>
         <td><a href="">Herta Berlin</a></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

There is probably a better solution for it, but I hope it helps a bit

Comment: No, it produces the default bootstrap output that I already had, except you enlarged the container. What I want is to position the content of each td in its middle and keep the text left aligned

Comment: Changed the code and included bootstrap. Don't know if its the best solution though

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered text-center">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="">Inter Milan</a></td>
    <td><span class="label label-default">0 - 1</span></td>
    <td><a href="">Lazzio Roma</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="">Bayern Munich</a></td>
    <td><span class="label label-default">3 - 3</span></td>
    <td><a href="">Herta Berlin</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Use `text-center` class and for border use `table-bordered` class

Comment: No, that's not what I want. I added a solution please check it.

Comment: Yeah! Almost same just i use extra class for **border**.